# What is the pooja vidhi of maa Gauri as described in shastras?

Tags: puranas, devi

Virgin girls in India worship maa Gauri. Now my questions are as follows:

1. What is swaroop (form) of maa Gauri? In detail, what is in her hands, what is the colour of body? what does she wear and How the murti of maa should be.
2. How to do Gauri pooja?
3. what are the days and festivals should be celebrated?
4. What are the days on which fast be observed?

Comment: http://www.mantraaonline.com/mangala-gowri-puja/

Comment: https://www.deepawali.co.in/jaya-parvati-vrat-katha-hindi-%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4.html

Comment: Please split it into several questions.

Comment: Fasts shd be observed on tuesdays. Mangala Gauri Vrata it is called. But remove the fast questions from this one and just focus on the Puja aspect. For fasts you can post a separate question.